# ASP.NET 5 NHibernate Session needs System.Data.IDbConnection?

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-core

How can I resolve a dependency in a vNext ASP.NET 5 project? When I try add a dependency in the project.json it cannot find **System.Data**.

I'm trying to close an NHibernate 4 ISession with `Session.Close()`.

```
try
{
    _transaction.Rollback();
}
finally
{
    Session.Close(); // Compiler error
}
```

> The type 'IDbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Comment: The way is: Create your own interface `IDataLayerSomething...` Give it `Open()` and `Close()`. Implement that in Data layer. Via IoC let it be injected into your project... no reference related to implementor will be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to **compile** by adding the dependency, which doesn't exist in ASP.NET 5.0, to the project.json.

```
"frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": {
        "frameworkAssemblies": {
            // Stuff in the global assembly cache(.net assemblies etc.)
            "System.Data" : "4.0.0.0" 
        }
    }
}
```

(I assume it works, my project isn't ready to test it out).

For more info on the new project and adding references and dependencies see the [overview on ASP.NET 5.0](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/what-s-new-with-asp-net-5).